# Difference between adding a method to an event and creating a method

Tags: c#, wpf, click

What is difference between adding a method button's click event and a creating a separate click method except they are created at different places? Do not they achieve same thing?

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startWorkButton.Click += async (sender, o) =>
        {
            startWorkButton.IsEnabled = false;
            workStartedTextBlock.Text = "Job Started";
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            startWorkButton.IsEnabled = true;
            workStartedTextBlock.Text = "Job Ended";
        };
    }

    //private async void startWorkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    startWorkButton.IsEnabled = false;
    //    workStartedTextBlock.Text = "Job Started";
    //    await Task.Delay(1000);
    //    startWorkButton.IsEnabled = true;
    //    workStartedTextBlock.Text = "Job Ended";
    //}
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. they achieve the same thing, though AFAIK the lambda syntax ends up with a slightly more complicated MSIL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basically it is the same.** Under the hood, the compiler generates a method called something that would not be legal in c# (like `<>lambdaFunc'1` or something like that). This is to ensure there is no method with that name defined by the programmer. This method may or may not be in a separate class, it **depends on a lot of things**. The important thing is that it is the same from your point of view. The reason they exist is to give you the freedom of not having to define a new method just for something you only use once. You don't have to give it a name, and it doesn't clutter your class.

Comment: thank you one more thing: Is it more helpful to add an existing event because it is done in MainWindow constructor? I mean when a MainWindows is created, it is guaranteed that this method will be added to the event everytime an object of MainWindow is created. Is this a good thing or a bad thing instead of creating a separate method?

Comment: You mean adding a defined method instead of a lambda function? It depends on the usecase. If it is a longer, more complicated method, then I would create a method for it, but if it is just a line, or just calling an other method with some parameters, then you are better off just passing in a lambda.

Comment: If you add it in the constructor, it doesn't matter whether you add a method or a lambda; it will be added everytime a MainWindow is created.

Comment: In your case, I would put it in a seperate method, because that way you don't have to search for it's implementation if you forget that you added it as a lambda. You can just see it in the class, and it will be easier to change. But that is just because it is long for my taste. But really, it doesn't matter

Comment: One more thing, the compiler won't generate more methods of the lambda function the more you use it. It generates one class with a method inside, maybe some fields. And then replaces your lambda function with the method that it generated.